# Pyinstaller exe single file executable on different computer

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I am trying to make a gui to control a spectrum analyzer. The code works when running from the IDE. I generate an .exe unsing pyinstaller with the code.`pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --icon=spec.ico spectrum_analyzer_gui.py` The .exe works great on the computer that generated it.

I tried to run the .exe on a different computer but got an error 'Failed to execute script spectrum_analyzer_gui'

I copied the icon to the same location.

What else do I need to do so the application runs on a different machine?

I have attached a like to a .zip in dropbox with the source code and build.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/87uqynllnlv72c4/Spectrum%20Analyzer%20Gui.zip?dl=0

Comment: Are you able to copy the exe to a different location on the same computer and run it successfully?

Comment: Yes, when I can change the location it still runs. I also changed the code so it doesn't start out with a VISA address.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `--hidden-import=tkinter` to your exe generation.